# How is to get user replay on Notes using message api and web hook in a LINE.me group?

Tags: line.me

I want to get *replay text* which has been posted in a **Notes** in **Line app**.

I can get all messages posted in a group using *weebhook*. But i cant have any information if a user post a replay in Notes.

Is is possible to get it using *message-api* ?

thanks in advance.